# How can I schedule VB functionality?

Tags: vba, automation

I am brand-flipping-new to visual basic.  I've been a Java/JSP programmer for about 15 years.  Never programmed in VB before in my life, but I've been handed a task to automate some functionality that is in a VB tool that was developed by someone else.  The functionality works, but currently it requires opening the tool and pushing a button.  We need this functionality to run every hour.  Can this be done in the VB code?  Or is this something I'll have to work into another technology (like my Java code)?

*edit*
What I've got is a button on a VB form that reads from a text log file and then processes the text and, based on the content, parses and stores it in a database.  I need this to happen on regular intervals and not on a local system.  The log file is written by a web service to a distributed server and the database is on a mainframe.  I've been tasked to do this using VB, but I really do not know if or how this could be done.

Comment: Change the code so that is does what the button makes it do in response to a command line "app.exe /doitnow" then use the built in Windows Task Scheduler to run it periodically.

Comment: Okay, I can see how this would be great for a local task.  My issue is that I need this to happen on a server, or even the mainframe.  I'm going to edit the original to add more details.  Thanks for your response!

Comment: Change your tags to get better answers, this isn't vbscript.

Comment: Done.  Thanks.  Like I said, I'm new to VB, period.  There's no "VB" or "visual-basic" tags out there, so I went with what I could find.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out that we are going to use an ESP scheduler to run the executable on the server.